# Eclipse - "other driver default" issue, driver files not specified

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently debugging my application in Eclipse and in the error logs it shows an error:

> Driver problems - problem with driver "other driver default" (Error:
>   driver files not specified in driver definition).

I have no idea where to start looking for the issue in order to resolve it. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: This doesn't look like a standard Eclipse message. Are you using Android or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferneces -> Driver Definitions, you will see an 'Other Driver' in Name column. If not create one using Add button. For the existing one, click 'Edit' and give path of your ojdbc jar in 'Jar list' tab and all the properties of your database in 'Properties' tab. check connection using 'Test connection'

Answer (score 0):

look at your preferences in eclipse, a good link about is https://www.eclipse.org/datatools/project_connectivity/connectivity_doc/DMF_I101205.html.

Answer (score 0):

click on New Connection profile -->new Driver definition-->Jar List-->add Zar/Zip-->ojdbc14-->then select driver class from properties . 
Then provide DB conneciton URL , username/password-jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:hostname"